# Unable to install QGIS ltr on Fedora

Tags: qgis, fedora

I'm trying to install the QGIS 3.22 ltr on Fedora because I need to use the SWAT+ plugin which does not work on QGIS 3.28. I'm on Fedora 38 and have forced the latest QGIS-ltr repo with the following (there is no QGIS-ltr repo available for Fedora 38):

```
sudo dnf copr enable dani/qgis-ltr fedora-37-x86_64
```

However, when I 'dnf search' for QGIS, I get the following error:

```
Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'copr:copr.fedorainfracloud.org:dani:qgis-ltr': 
Cannot download repomd.xml: Cannot download repodata/repomd.xml: All mirrors were tried
```